# gretel gem in rails engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, erb, breadcrumbs

i am working with Rails 4.1.8. Is here someone who worked with gretel in an rails engine before? How do I get breadcrumbs into my rails engine? Can someone post an working example, that would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please look into this [use gretel gem with example](https://www.omniref.com/ruby/gems/gretel/2.1.0) and get some idea with proper details and implement this.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Links die (seemingly like yours), please add relevant details to your answer.